# Disable button as long as the email address is not correct R Shiny

Tags: r, shiny

I created a shiny app and I configured a "send" button to be disabled until the settings are completed. I would like to set the same thing as long as the email address has not been verified. I'm not sure about my code:

```
 #-------- DISABLED SEND BUTTON --------#
      observe({
        if(is.null(input$zip) || input$zip == ""){
          disable("send")
        } else if(is.null(input$indice) || input$indice == ""){
          disable("send")
        } else if(!grepl("\\<[A-Z0-9._%+-]+@[A-Z0-9.-]+\\.[A-Z]{2,}\\>", input$mail)){
          disable("send")
        }
        else{
          enable("send")
        }

  })
```

Comment: your code allows only capital letters

Comment: oh you are right. It's better like this : `"\\<[A-Za-z0-9._%+-]+@[A-Za-z0-9.-]+\\.[A-Za-z]{2,}\\>"`.   And it works ! Thank you @Eli Berkow

Comment: exactly, glad to help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simple example for others:

```
library(shiny)
library(shinyjs)

ui <- fluidPage(
    useShinyjs(),
    textInput('mail', 'mail'),
    actionButton("send", "send")
)

server <- function(input, output) {
    observe({
        #if(is.null(input$zip) || input$zip == ""){
        #    disable("send")
        #} else if(is.null(input$indice) || input$indice == ""){
        #    disable("send")
        #} else 
        if(!grepl("\\<[a-zA-Z0-9._%+-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9.-]+\\.[a-zA-Z]{2,}\\>", input$mail)){
            disable("send")
        }
        else{
            enable("send")
        }
    })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```